# How to retrieve javascript variable (an array) and its content using HtmlUnit

Tags: javascript, facebook, htmlunit

I am using HtmlUnit to get a page from server.
the page has lots of javascript and i want to get some variable values (array, json etc) from page.
Is there a way to get all the global variables?
the code i am using to get variable is as below

```
ScriptResult scr = result.executeJavaScript("User");
scr.getJavaScriptResult();
```

when i print this variable it shows `[object Object]` how do i get properties of this variable. I know that there is a property "id" so i can simply call `result.executeJavaScript("User.id")` but there are some more which i don't know at this time. how i can see all the properties?
same problem is with the Json object

```
var Item = {Locations: {"1":{"name":"New York", "desc":"xyz"}}
```

the same issue is here

```
result.executeJavaScript("Item.Locations");
```

return `[object Object]`, Is there any way to get whole json object at once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so i find that `[object object]` is nothing but an instance of `NativeObject` so simply cast it and traverse using iterator
`Iterator<Entry<Object,Object>> entryset = ((NativeObject)scr.getJavaScriptResult()).entrySet().iterator();`